# Typescript does not show error for optional type?

Tags: typescript

I see the following in VSCode:

I have a method that accepts a config opbject of the following shape:

[image]

`sync.user` has the following type, though:

[image]

Clearly, the method expects the user not to be optional but does not produce a linting error when user is passed of type `User | undefined`. I don't understand why?

Comment: who knows? you haven't shown the definition of User or DigestService

Comment: Do you have `strictNullChecks` enabled?

Comment: @szaman does it matter? AFAIK, the method contract should not depend on the implementation of the class (digestService) or some inner shape of a type (User). User has a defined shape and is NOT `type User = undefined`.

Comment: Yes, in my .tsconfig I have `strict: true` which should enable all strict checks for my project.

Comment: maybe you already have a check like if(!sync.user)?

Comment: Hm, no the type is not narrowed in any way. The second screenshot shows the cursor right over the variable. If it was narrowed it would not show the user was optional.

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) and provide a [mre] so that others can easily demonstrate your issue for themselves.